# Bootstrap Dropdownlist Issue in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use ng-repeat in bootstrap dropdown menu, but it does not display the list of elements in drop down. am i missing anything in populating the elements of drop down list from a method defined in controller.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="Results Per Page">
  <span class="dropdown" dropdown>
     <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
       <span class="caret"></span>
      {{Temp.obj.pageSize}} Results Per Page </a>     
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li data-ng-repeat="result in Temp.obj.availPages">
            <a href data-ng-click="Temp.obj.setSize(result)">                            
                 {{result}}</a>
            </li>
           </ul>
    </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simple missing the `dropdown-menu` directive in the `ul` list.

As a reminder, here is the (simplified) example from the angular-ui bootstrap doc.

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
  <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It looks like you are using an old version of angular-ui bootstrap when the directive were not prefixed by `uib-`. I recommend updating your version if you can. Otherwise, just remove the prefixs from the example.

Edit: As you are using the version 1.1.2 of angular-ui bootstrap, you need to prefix the directives as shown in this answer. And here is [the doc for reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.1.2/#/dropdown)

Comment: I added the directive but still the data is not populated on the dropdown list...

Comment: which version of angular-ui bootstrap do you use?

Comment: I have multiple versions in the scripts folder for angular 1.2.2, 1.3 and 1.5.and  bootstrap version 3.2.0.

Comment: 1.5 seems to be the angular version, not the angular-ui bootstrap. It is important to know your angular-ui bootstrap version because as I explained the directive names have changed with the versions.

Comment: ok, so now we need to know the version of the angular-ui bootstrap library: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: ui bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js is the version .

Comment: ok so according to the doc for that version, you need to prefix the directive: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.1.2/#/dropdown If you copy/paste the snippet of the answer the dropdown menu should work as expected. Then you will be able to test with your ng-repeat in order to isolate the cause of the issue. But using the updated template with prefixed directives should be enough.

Comment: now that i changed to use uib- as prefix to dropdown-menu, its working but when ever i click on the dropdown or make a selection, its displaced to either left or right. and also the dropdown when it is populated it doesnot populate exactly under the button. how should i fix these position issues. Thank you so much.