# ng-repeat only populates last entry in array when used with uib-dropdown

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to populate a drop down menu using UI Bootstrap's uib-dropdown and ng-repeat but only the last record in the array is being populated.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/resources/')}" class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
            <a uib-dropdown-toggle class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Resources <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul ng-repeat="resource in TN.resourceList" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{{ resource.ResourceLink }}" target="_blank">{{ resource.ResourceText }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've confirmed that `TN.resourceList` has 3 records.

If I remove: `class="dropdown-menu"`

from: `<ul ng-repeat="resource in TN.resourceList" class="dropdown-menu">`

then all the records display but it no longer renders as a drop down menu.

I also tried adding the `uib-dropdown-menu` directive to the `<ul>` with the `ng-repeat` on it as well as the `role` attributes as suggested in this answer: [Bootstrap Dropdownlist Issue in angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730481/bootstrap-dropdownlist-issue-in-angular-js)

But it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
       <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/resources/')}" class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
                <a uib-dropdown-toggle class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Resources <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li ng-repeat="resource in TN.resourceList"><a href="{{ resource.ResourceLink }}" target="_blank">{{ resource.ResourceText }}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Notice the ng-repeat on the `li` instead of the `ul` dom element (ng-repeat repeats elements where it added to and it's childeren).

Answer (score 2):

You're repeating the `dropdown-menu` itself. You should have one `dropdown-menu` and repeat the `li` instead:

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/resources/')}" class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
            <a uib-dropdown-toggle class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Resources <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="resource in TN.resourceList"><a href="{{ resource.ResourceLink }}" target="_blank">{{ resource.ResourceText }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest answer is to consider looking at the ng-repeat itself as a loop. Within normal html, you wouldn't want to have multiple lists or 'ul' tags would you? You would want one list with multiple entries or 'li' tags.

Consider the answers above as direct answers, but realistically, you should be able to look at your code and figure out that you want to repeat the list entries and not the list itself.